# writing in Python fir1 matlab with Scipy firwin

Tags: python, matlab, scipy, signal-processing

I need to translate signal processing Matlab package to Python. And I'm stuck in fir1  function. Fir1 description in Matlab:
`b = fir1(n,Wn)` uses a Hamming window to design an nth-order lowpass, bandpass, or multiband FIR filter with linear phase. The filter type depends on the number of elements of Wn.

I tried:

```
import scipy
b = scipy.signal.firwin(11,.5, window = "hamming", pass_zero = False)
-0.00506032, -0.  0.04194288, -0. -0.28848483, 0.49679547, -0.28848483,
 -0. 0.04194288, -0.  -0.00506032
```

while in Matlab, or Octave:

```
   fir1(10,.5)
0.00505978  -0.00016286  -0.04194054   0.00066187   0.28847599   0.49581153   0.28847599    
-0.00016286   0.00505978
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From Matlab's [fir documentation](https://in.mathworks.com/help/signal/ref/fir1.html),

> If Wn is a scalar, then fir1 designs a **lowpass or highpass** filter with cutoff frequency Wn...

Thus, it seems that providing `pass_zero = False` might not correspond to Matlab's result. Instead, try `pass_zero='lowpass'` for proper comparison.

Comment: scipy.signal.firwin(11,.5, window = "hamming", pass_zero = 'lowpass') gives: 5.06031712e-03, -3.25061549e-18, -4.19428794e-02,  1.32104345e-17,
        2.88484826e-01,  4.96795472e-01,  2.88484826e-01,  1.32104345e-17,
       -4.19428794e-02, -3.25061549e-18,  5.06031712e-03

Comment: I think you have missed to write some of the output from Matlab's `fir1` command in your question. It should have 11 columns. Whereas there are only 9 columns in your output. Anyway, when I issue `format longe; fir1(10, 0.5)` in Matlab, I get the following output: `[5.060317124844847e-03, -3.250615490734487e-18, -4.194287943134473e-02,  1.321043449104680e-17, 2.884848263026376e-01,  4.967954720077247e-01, 2.884848263026376e-01,  1.321043449104680e-17, -4.194287943134473e-02, -3.250615490734487e-18, 5.060317124844847e-03]` which, in my opinion, is close to what you get from scipy's `firwin`.